# Why Google Sheets Crud/ search form is not working if has more than 5 columns?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a simple app that will display search window and the results based on the range in google sheets. However I have a problem that I cannot understand at all.

The code is working perfect till I have 5 columns to display (search.html). If it is more than 5 it is not displaying anything....

I don't know how can I explain it more so if you have any question please let me know. Also console is not giving any error

I have no idea why. If anyone could help me with that I would be grateful.

CRUD.gs

```
function loadMainForm(){

   const htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("main");
   const html = htmlServ.evaluate();
   html.setWidth(950).setHeight(600)
   
   const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
         ui.showModalDialog(html, "データ検索");   
}

function createMenu(){
   const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   const menu = ui.createMenu("データ検索");
  
  menu.addItem("検索フォームを開く", "loadMainForm");
  menu.addToUi();
}

function onOpen(){
  createMenu();
}
```

main.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
　　　
   <style>
   .nav-link {
   cursor: pointer;
   }
   </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="container">
    
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-link active" id="home-link">Home</div>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <div class="nav-link"id="search-link">検索</div>
  </li>

</ul>

     <div id="app"></div>    
  <!-- Content here -->
</div>

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    
  <script>
  
  var data;
  
  function loadView(options){
var id = typeof options.id === "undefined" ? "app" : options.id;
var cb = typeof options.callback === "undefined" ? function(){} : options.callback;

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(html){
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = html;
typeof options.params === "undefined" ? cb() : cb(options.params);
})[options.func]();
}

function setDataForSearch(){
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(dataReturned){
data = dataReturned.slice();
}).getDataForSearch();
}

function search(){

var searchinput = document.getElementById("searchinput").value;
var resultsArray = data.filter(function(r){
//return r[1].indexOf(searchinput) !== -1;
return r[0].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchinput.toString().toLowerCase()) !== -1;
});
var searchResultsBox = document.getElementById("searchResults");
var templateBox = document.getElementById("rowTemplate");
var template = templateBox.content;
searchResultsBox.innerHTML = "";
resultsArray.forEach(function(r){

var tr = template.cloneNode(true);
var hinmokuColumn = tr.querySelector(".hinmoku");
var buhinCodeuColumn = tr.querySelector(".buhinCode");
var buhinNameColumn = tr.querySelector(".buhinName");
var hitsuyoColumn = tr.querySelector(".hitsuyo");
var genkaColumn = tr.querySelector(".genka");
var kobaiColumn = tr.querySelector(".kobai");
var sagakuColumn = tr.querySelector(".sagaku");
var kenshoColumn = tr.querySelector(".kensho");

hinmokuColumn.textContent = r[0];
buhinCodeuColumn.textContent = r[1];
buhinNameColumn.textContent = r[2];
hitsuyoColumn.textContent = r[3];
genkaColumn.textContent = r[4];
kobaiColumn.textContent = r[5];
sagakuColumn.textContent = r[6];
kenshoColumn.textContent = r[7];

searchResultsBox.appendChild(tr);

});
}

function loadSearchView(){
loadView({func:"loadSearchView", callback: setDataForSearch});
}


document.getElementById("search-link").addEventListener("click",loadSearchView);


function inputEventHandler(e){
if (e.target.matches("#searchinput")){
  search();
}
}
document.getElementById("app").addEventListener("input",inputEventHandler);
    
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

search.html

```
<h1>検索</h1>

<div class="form-group">  
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchinput" placeholder="検索">
 </div>

<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      
      <th scope="col">品目</th>
      <th scope="col">部品コード</th>
      <th scope="col">部品名</th>
      <th scope="col">必要数</th>
      <th scope="col">原価</th>
      <th scope="col">購買原価</th>
      <th scope="col">差額1ヶ</th>
      <th scope="col">検証状況</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="searchResults">
  
  </tbody>
</table>


<template id="rowTemplate">
 <tr>
      
      <td class="hinmoku"></td>
      <td class="buhinCode"></td>
      <td class="buhinName""></td>
      <td class="hitsuyo"></td>
      <td class="genka"></td>
      <td class="kobai"></td>
      <td class="sagaku"></td>
      <td class="kensho"></td>

  </tr>
</template>
```

loadPartial.gs

```
function loadPartialHTML_(partial) {
  const htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(partial);
  return htmlServ.evaluate().getContent();
  
}

function loadSearchView(){
 
   return loadPartialHTML_("search");
}
```

serverSideFuncs.gs

```
function getDataForSearch(){
    
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Array");
  
  return ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow(),8).getValues();

}
```

Comment: In the last line of your code `ws.getLastRow()` should be `ws.getLastRow()-1` it's the number of rows not the number of the last row.  That's probably not your problem, I can't read Chinese of whatever it is.  If your going to geta data for a search then why use ws.getLastColumn() in the last parameter of the getRange()

Comment: In your `search.html`, it seems that the double quote is not closed at `<td class="buhinName""></td>`. I think that in this case, an error occurs at `htmlServ.evaluate()`. How about this?

Comment: This could be correct but I'm having a hard time seeing the original function call to the server. `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(html){
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = html;
typeof options.params === "undefined" ? cb() : cb(options.params);
})[options.func]();
}` and what's the point of the line with the typeof their doesn't seem to be anything t here to receive the output of the terniary.

Comment: By the way, in your script, when `search-link` is clicked, 2 `google.script.run` are run. So after the HTML of `search.html` is loaded, when you input the search value immediately, the script might not be run because `data` is not retrieved by 2nd `google.script.run`. So please be careful this. And, I think that your script works for showing the columns over 5 columns. So can you provide the detail information for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike as always thanks for your advice! The problem was due to double quote in `<td class="buhinName"></td>` deleting that one quote fixed a problem! 
相変わらずポカミスでした！　笑

Comment: Thank you for replying. It's no problem. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it might be useful for other users.

Comment: you can post it and I will accept it :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `search.html`, it seems that the double quote is not closed at `<td class="buhinName""></td>`. In this case, an error occurs at `htmlServ.evaluate()`. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
<td class="buhinName""></td>
```

#### To:

```
<td class="buhinName"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the restructions of, withSuccessHandler, parameters. Can be relevant.
[1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#code.gs)Most types are legal, but not Date, Function, or DOM element besides form; see description

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).